# UTF8 literal on obj-c code - can't make it work on real device

Tags: objective-c, xcode, character-encoding

I have strange behavior with UTF8 encoding:

For example: when i run on simulator

```
NSString *uni   = @"\U0001d11e";
NSString *uni2  = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:"\xF0\x9D\x84\x9E"];
NSString *uni3  = @"";
NSLog(@"unicode: %@ and %@ and %@",uni, uni2, uni3);
```

I've got the expected result:

```
unicode:  and  and
```

But when i ran it into a real device, here the output:

```
unicode: ùÑû and ùÑû and ùÑû
```

I can't understand why. It is a compilation workaround, or something that i didn't understood?
I know that the @"" construct can only take ASCII characters. But why this is working on simulator? Do you have an idea on how i can make it works on real device? Thx

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem, but in recent versions of Xcode, you can add UTF-8 characters in source code and in literal strings with no problem... Also, I note that, on my Mac, the Unicode character 0001D111E seems to exist only in the *Apple Symbols* font, and this font isn't present on iOS, maybe that's the problem...

Comment: Where do you look at the log? I created a new iOS project and run it on an iPhone and the output looks fine to me in both the Xcode console and organizer device console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working fine, the bytes are received correctly. It's just that the device is decoding them as [Mac OS Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) instead of UTF-8. All you need to do is to specify to the device that the input is UTF-8. If you don't know how to do that, then you should provide more details.